# $watch not firing on same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function that sorts cases for me on the front end, which is invoked on an ng-click. the parameter is a string, the parameter 'asc' is passed to vm.sortCases for ascending sorts, and for descending sort, 'desc'.

```
 vm.sortCases = function (byValue) {
      vm.selectedSorting = byValue;
    };
```

I have a watch set up as follows, which watches vm.selectedSorting, which contains a string:

```
 $scope.$watch('vm.selectedSorting', filterAndSortingSearch);
```

Callback for the watch:

```
function filterAndSortingSearch(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue === oldValue) {
            return;
          }
          fetchData();
        }
```

If the user clicks on asc twice, the watch only fires once (the first time), why is that, and how can I get the watches callback to run even when the same string is passed? I would like it so when the user clicks twice and 'asc' is passed twice  the watch fires twice as well, which isn't happening now. I tried passing true as a third parameter in the watch but that didn't work.  I also tried converting the string like this:

```
 vm.sortCases = function (byValue) {
      var objForEqualityComparison = {sortOrder: byValue}
      vm.selectedSorting = objForEqualityComparison.sortOrder;
    };
```

This is what I ended up going with. I converted the string to be inside an object and watched the object instead of the string value:

```
vm.sortCases = function (byValue) {
      vm.selectedSorting = {direction: byValue};
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) only fires when a variable *changes* values:

> `$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`
>
> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes. [...] The listener is called only when the value from the current watchExpression and the previous call to watchExpression are not equal (with the exception of the initial run, see below).

This is by design - a variable can be re-set in the course of a calculation, but end up being the same value, at which point `$watch` shouldn't trigger since nothing else depending on that variable's value will have changed either.

If you want an action to fire each time a user clicks on a button, then you should use onclick or ng-click.

Comment: Is there any way to get the variable to be considered as new each time a user clicks? I thought a conversion to an object would handle that? For other reasons, I can't use ng-click in this scenario

Comment: Hmm yes, make something like `function AlwaysUnique(s) { this.s = s: }` and on click always set to `new AlwaysUnique("asc")`, and make sure the watch is using strict equality. Hacky but it should work ..

Comment: strict equality is via true as the third parameter, correct?

Comment: Edited my post to show what I went with -- couldn't get your suggestion to work for some reason